# What are the advantages of using WCF over frameworks like MassTransit or hand written MSMQ client?

Tags: wcf, architecture, msmq, soa, masstransit

I am looking at using MSMQ as a solution to do asynchronous execution in my upcoming project. I want to know the differences between using WCF and frameworks like MassTransit or even hand written MSMQ client to place/read task off MSMQ.

Basically the application will be several websites (internal through LAN or external through the Internet) reading/writing data through a service layer (be it WCF or normal web service). Then this service layer will do one of two things: 1. write data to database 2. and/or trigger the background process by placing a message in the queue. 3. obviously it can also retrieve data from database. The little agent (a windows service) on the other side of the queue will monitor the queue and execute based on the task command.

This architecture will be quite easy to scale (add more queues and agents) and easy to implement compared to RPC or distributed execution or whatever. And the agent processing doesn’t need to be real time. And the agent and service layer are separate applications except they share the common domain objects and Repositories etc.

What do you think? Architecture suggestions for the above requirements are welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: You mention "be it WCF or normal web service". If you mean ASMX web services, I recommend you don't use them - they are the past, and WCF is the present.

Comment: yes i meant asmx, in terms of SOA i still live in the past. LOL

Comment: 7 years down the line, WCF for web services is also the past :-) It is Web API now in 2016

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WCF adds an abstraction over MSMQ. In fact, once you define compatible contracts (operations must be OneWay), you can switch out MSMQ in the config, transparently. (For instance, you could switch to normal HttpWS or a NetTcp binding.)

You should evaluate the other WCF benefits, like security and so on, to see how those fit in with your needs. Again, they should be reasonably transparent of the fact you're using MSMQ underneath. For instance, adding SOAP security and so on should "just work", independent of using MSMQ.

(Although, IIRC, you still need to login to the desktop on each machine that uses MSMQ, *with the service account that will use MSMQ*, to generate the certificate in the machines local profile. And then, it doesn't work very well from IIS6, since user profiles aren't loaded. A real pain in general, but nothing to do with WCF specifically.)

---

Apart from that:

Have you looked at SQL Server Service Broker? After using MSMQ + WCF and SSSB, I think that SSSB is *vastly* easier to configure and manage. SSSB works with T-SQL commands over any SQL client (I use it from Mono, on Linux, with transactions). It'll also give you transactional send/receive, even remotely (I think MSMQ 4 now allows this). It really takes a lot of the pain away from message queuing, and if you're using SQL Server already...

SSSB is often overlooked since the SQL Management Studio doesn't have GUI designers for it all, but it isn't hard and is a great option. The one downside is that if you want local send capability (i.e., queue message when network is down), you'll need to run a local SQL Express instance.

Comment: How many million messages an hour are you looking to process? Once you bring transactions into the mix, SSSB can be vastly faster than MSMQ, right? Local trans versus DTC? But hey, if you don't want to use SQL, that's another story.

Comment: At any rate, as my main answer points out, WCF gives you the WCF programming, security, etc. model and isn't specific to MSMQ for the most part.

Answer (score 2):

Your architecture seems sound and reasonable. However you should consider using the WCF net MSMQ transport over hand coded MSMQ classes. WCF wraps this common functionality into a nice programming model. Also I believe there is some improvements in the protocol used by wcf compared to basic System.Messaging

Comment: The .NET MSMQ API gives you access to things that WCF-MSMQ hides away.  Like the lovely [MessageQueue.DefaultPropertiesToSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea4ffdsh(v=vs.110).aspx), so depending on your needs you may want to use MSMQ directly.  I agree there is no need to hand-code .NET classes around native MSMQ

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the value-add over plain MSMQ:

http://readthedocs.org/docs/masstransit/en/latest/overview/valueadd.html

In summary, you get a lot of messaging concepts clearly presented in the API with MassTransit; to an extent you wouldn't have if you hand-coded it or used WCF.